# Opencart product view issue

Tags: php, opencart

When the product view is opened, I get the error below.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   ModelCatalogProduct::getSpecialPriceEnd() in
>   /home/hoxzaz3/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_category.php

[image]

site url : http://7hox.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=97

Comment: locate and resolve that error  at`vq2-catalog_controller_product_category.php on line 239`

Comment: It's caused by an extension (I guess a countdown extension) not by OpenCart. There's no `getSpecialPriceEnd` function by default.